# How can I only show a subset of xtick labels in seaborn catplot of scatter plots?

Tags: python, seaborn

My seaborn catplot of scatter plots is displaying either all xaxis tick labels (overlapping, looking like a black bar) or none. How do I show a subset of 2 (the min and max) on the x axis of each scatter plot within the catplot?

```
sns.catplot(x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", col="continent", s=7,
            data=df_2007_no_nulls, height=4, col_wrap=3);
```

This code displays the 5 scatter plots in a faceted grid as expected but some of the scatter plots have no xtick labels and some seem to be displaying all of them, overlapping, which looks terrible. [image: catplot of scatter plots]

I was expecting only a handful of xtick labels to be displayed in the same way that they are when I display a single scatter plot (without using catplot):

[image: a single scatter plot]

(If there's not enough space to display 5 xtick labels in a readable way, then I'd like to display at least the min (0) and max (50000) in small text, and rotated 90 degrees if needed.)

Comment: `catplot` stands for categorical plot, so you get one label per category. Seems you'd rather want to use a `relplot` instead?

Comment: Ahhh! I see! Thanks ImportanceOfBeingErnest! That fixed it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `**relplot**` (instead of `catplot`) fixed this.

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest for providing the solution.

My code now looks like this and displays the x axis tick labels nicely:

```
sns.relplot(x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", col="continent", s=20,
            data=df_2007_no_nulls, height=4, col_wrap=3);
```